How to add vertical line to existing plot in matplotlib
I have a large dataset (5M points) to visualise. There are datapoints and time axes.
There are events in time, where values changing significantly.
I want to add two 'clickable' elements in form of vertical lines to mark two of mentioned events, later I want to display time values of them and calculated difference.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

time = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,13,15,16,17,18,19,20]
ch1_scope = [0,0,0,0,5,5,5,5,0,0,0,0,5,5,5,5,0,0,0,0]
ch2_scope = [5,5,5,5,0,0,0,0,5,5,5,5,0,0,0,0,5,5,5,5]

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, sharex = True)

ax1.plot(time, ch1_scope, 'tab:red') 
ax1.set_title("Vph1")
ax2.plot(time, ch2_scope, 'tab:olive')
ax2.set_title("Vph2")

This minimal code produces:

How can I achieve it with matplotlib? Is it even possible without re-plotting/re-drawing?
A simple script where adding vertical lines is possible it would be a good start.
After some tries I added this cursor:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Cursor

time = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,13,15,16,17,18,19,20]
ch1_scope = [0,0,0,0,5,5,5,5,0,0,0,0,5,5,5,5,0,0,0,0]
ch2_scope = [5,5,5,5,0,0,0,0,5,5,5,5,0,0,0,0,5,5,5,5]

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, sharex = True)

ax1.plot(time, ch1_scope, 'tab:red') 
ax1.set_title("Vph1")
ax2.plot(time, ch2_scope, 'tab:olive')
ax2.set_title("Vph2")

cursor = Cursor(
ax1, useblit=True, horizOn=False, vertOn=True, color="red", linewidth=0.5)

plt.show()


This is not satisfactory, as doesn't bring cursor permanently (zooming kills it). Also, there is no option for dynamical addition of notations on the plot.
Added part of click event. This bring some current mouse position information to the console. How to transfer it to the plot?
enter code here
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Cursor
from matplotlib.backend_bases import MouseButton

time = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,13,15,16,17,18,19,20]
ch1_scope = [0,0,0,0,5,5,5,5,0,0,0,0,5,5,5,5,0,0,0,0]
ch2_scope = [5,5,5,5,0,0,0,0,5,5,5,5,0,0,0,0,5,5,5,5]

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, sharex = True)

ax1.plot(time, ch1_scope, 'tab:red') 
ax1.set_title("Vph1")
ax2.plot(time, ch2_scope, 'tab:olive')
ax2.set_title("Vph2")

cursor = Cursor(
    ax1, useblit=True, horizOn=False, vertOn=True, color="red", linewidth=0.5
)

def on_move(event):
    if event.inaxes:
        print(f'data coords {event.xdata} {event.ydata},',
              f'pixel coords {event.x} {event.y}')


def on_right_click(event):
    if event.button is MouseButton.LEFT:
        print(f'Clicked LMB: data coords {event.xdata} {event.ydata}')
    if event.button is MouseButton.RIGHT:
        print('disconnecting callback')
        plt.disconnect(binding_id)
        
        
binding_id = plt.connect('motion_notify_event', on_move)
plt.connect('button_press_event', on_right_click)

plt.show()


Please share what you have tried so far.

Working script, showing cursor in its 'cross' shape (to help with precision).
Also showing results on the plot.

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from matplotlib.backend_bases import MouseEvent, MouseButton


class Cursor:
    """
    A cross hair cursor.
    """
    def __init__(self, ax):
        self.ax = ax
        #self.mytext = ''
        self.horizontal_line = ax.axhline(color='k', lw=0.8, ls='--')
        self.vertical_line = ax.axvline(color='k', lw=0.8, ls='--')
        # text location in axes coordinates
        self.text = ax.text(0.50, 0.9, '', transform=ax.transAxes) # text in plot area coordinates
        self.text_calculations = ax.text(0.1, 0.1, 'Calc: ', transform=ax.transAxes)
        self.click_x_value = []

    def set_cross_hair_visible(self, visible):
        need_redraw = self.horizontal_line.get_visible() != visible
        self.horizontal_line.set_visible(visible)
        self.vertical_line.set_visible(visible)
        self.text.set_visible(visible)
        return need_redraw
    
    def on_click(self, event):
        if event.button is MouseButton.LEFT:
            self.click_x_value.append(f'{event.xdata:1.3f}')
            if len(self.click_x_value) == 2:
                diff = float(self.click_x_value[1]) - float(self.click_x_value[0])
                recip = 1/diff
                self.text_calculations.set_text('x0: ' + str(self.click_x_value[0]) + ', x1: ' + str(self.click_x_value[1]) +'\n'
                                                             +'Difference: ' + str(diff) + '\n' + 'Reciprocal: ' + str(recip))
                self.click_x_value = []
                
            self.ax.figure.canvas.draw()


    def on_mouse_move(self, event):
        if not event.inaxes:
            need_redraw = self.set_cross_hair_visible(False)
            if need_redraw:
                self.ax.figure.canvas.draw()
        else:
            self.set_cross_hair_visible(True)
            x, y = event.xdata, event.ydata
            # update the line positions
            self.horizontal_line.set_ydata([y])
            self.vertical_line.set_xdata([x])
            self.text.set_text(f'x={x:1.2f}, y={y:1.2f}') # text appears in plot area
                
            self.ax.figure.canvas.draw()


time = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,13,15,16,17,18,19,20]
ch1_scope = [0,0,0,0,5,5,5,5,0,0,0,0,5,5,5,5,0,0,0,0]
ch2_scope = [5,5,5,5,0,0,0,0,5,5,5,5,0,0,0,0,5,5,5,5]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_title('Simple cursor')
ax.plot(time, ch1_scope)

cursor = Cursor(ax)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', cursor.on_mouse_move)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', cursor.on_click)

There is an answer in SO wrt adding lines (by mouse click) in plot:
collect mouse click location with matplotlib ginput and draw vertical line through location
Just need to implement in above and the solution is ready.
